# android onTaskRemoved() not called on mi (xiomi)

Tags: android, service

I am using a service in my app. I want to show a button when the app is removed from the recent's screen. For this i am using the onTaskRemoved() method of the service. Everything is working fine except on mi (xiomi) phone or tablet. I am printing a log when the onTaskRemoved() method is called. The log is printed on all the devices except for mi(xiomi). Also i am printing a log when the service is created. The log is shown but i takes a lot of time to print. This behavior is observed only on mi(xiomi). Can anyone help.

Comment: The same happens on an Huawei phone. This method never gets called. Did you reach any conclusion in your case?